# Unity3D - C# script communication with a process (Ubuntu)

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, unity-game-engine

Hello stackoverflow community

First of all, sorry for my limited english skills but I try my best to explain my problem.

My program runs on a Linux Ubuntu system. It runs fine without the following code lines. But I want to start a new terminal and furthermore I have to put in some arguments (change directory, start a simulation, configuration parameters, and so on). As you can see I test it with an "echo" command but nothing happen in the terminal. Therefore, I would like to ask if it's possible to write "strings" as Unix commands into the standard input of a terminal using a C# script and Unity3D.

When I execute my project, a new terminal (Ubuntu) appears but in the window where normally occurs the game, there is only a whitescreen.

Btw, the code is in the Start()-method of a game object.

```
    Process myProcess = new Process();

    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "gnome-terminal";
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    myProcess.Start();
    myProcess.WaitForExit();

    String inputText = "echo Test";
    myProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(inputText);
```

When I execute it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjGQ6.jpg)

Thank you very much

Regards

Devel

Comment: HAve you tried to use `CreateNoWindow`? and another thing is you call `WaitForExit()` so unity will freeze until the process ( "terminal" ) ends up

Comment: I would suggest you to create a batch file with the commands you want and execute the batch file through the process.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh Yes, it would be the easiest way to do it, but I get some parameters only during the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i see 2 problems in here which you can improve/fix:

**1.** You should hide the terminal window (or just try to) by adding this line:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

**2.** You should remove the blocking part `myProcess.WaitForExit()` because it will just hang your Unity game until terminal window is closed.

**EDIT**:

To ensure it's all working you should do:

```
myProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("echo Test");
myProcess.StandardInput.Flush(); // to actauly send it

string echoValue = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
Assert(echoValue == "Test");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. It fixes the problem with the white screen, but unfortunately nothing happen in the new terminal. It's still started but it doesn't execute the echo command.

Comment: That's why i think you should make some object to deal with process handling. After starting terminal you should wait some time to be able to use another process IO.

Comment: I'm uncertain if I truly understand your answer. I put a "timer" into the C# script which waits 10 seconds after the terminal starts, but in the new terminal is still no output from the echo command visible.

Comment: How do you know it's not visible? You have redirected stdout from console window `myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;` Do something like `stdin << "echo test"` and then read `stdout`.

Comment: It doesn't work. I try "echo Hello > hello.txt" to test it. I also try your suggestion with an  Assert but I don`t get any output, no errors...nothing, even if the test string is different (no exception occurs).

Comment: Instead of `WriteLine("echo test")` try `WriteLine("sensible-browser")`.

Comment: Unfortunately no )= I have no idea what's going wrong...always the game window and the new terminal open but that's everything

Comment: Strange. I have used almost the same piece of code and it was running smooth on linux mint. The only difference is that i used sh file instead of terminal.

Comment: Maybe you could send me a code snippet of your program?